# C++ memory leak that I can't find

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, microcontroller

I have a small example program here for the particle photon that has a memory bug that I cannot figure out.

What it does: loads up a buffer with small string chunks, converts that large buffer back into a string.  Then it creates a bunch of objects that are only wrappers for small chunks of buffer. It does this repetitively, and I don't allocate any new memory after the setup(), yet the memory goes down slowly until it crashes.

## main.cpp

## includes, variable declarations

```
#include "application.h" //needed when compiling spark locally

#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include "dummyclass.h"

using namespace std;
SYSTEM_MODE(MANUAL);

char* buffer;
unordered_map<int, DummyClass*> store;
string alphabet;
unsigned char alphabet_range;
unsigned char state;
int num_chars;

static const unsigned char STATE_INIT = 0;
static const unsigned char STATE_LOAD_BUFFER = 1;
static const unsigned char STATE_PREP_FOR_DESERIALIZE = 2;
static const unsigned char STATE_FAKE_DESERIALIZE = 3;
static const unsigned char STATE_FINISH_RESTART = 4;
```

## delete objects helper function

```
bool delete_objects()
{
    Serial.println("deleting objects in 'store'");
    for(auto iter = store.begin(); iter != store.end(); iter++)
    {
        delete iter->second;
        iter->second = nullptr;
    } 
    store.clear();

    if(store.empty())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

## set up function, allocates memory, initial assignments

```
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial1.begin(38400);
    delay(2000);

    buffer = new char[9000];
    alphabet = string("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789~!@#$^&*()_-?/><[]{}|");
    alphabet_range = alphabet.length() - 1;
    state = STATE_INIT;
    num_chars = 0;
}
```

## loop function, gets run over and over

```
void loop()
{
    switch(state){
        case STATE_INIT: {

            strcpy(buffer, "");
            state = STATE_LOAD_BUFFER;
            delay(1000);
            break;

        }
        case STATE_LOAD_BUFFER: {

            if(num_chars < 6000){
                string chunk;
                for(char i = 0; i < 200; i++){
                    int index = rand() % alphabet_range;
                    chunk.append(alphabet.substr(index, 1));
                    num_chars++;
                }
                strcat(buffer, chunk.c_str());
            }
            else{
                num_chars = 0;
                state = STATE_PREP_FOR_DESERIALIZE;
            }
            delay(500);
            break;

        }
        case STATE_PREP_FOR_DESERIALIZE: {

            Serial.println("\nAttempting to delete current object set...");
            delay(500);
            if(delete_objects())
                Serial.println("_delete_objects succeeded");
            else {
                Serial.println("_delete_objects failed");
                break;
            }
            state = STATE_FAKE_DESERIALIZE;
            delay(1000);
            break;

        }
        case STATE_FAKE_DESERIALIZE: {

            string buff_string(buffer);
            if(buff_string.length() == 0){
                Serial.println("Main:: EMPTY STRING CONVERTED FROM BUFFER");
            }

            int index = 0;
            int key = 1;
            while(index < buff_string.length())
            {
                int amount = (rand() % 50) + 5;
                DummyClass* dcp = new DummyClass(buff_string.substr(index, amount));
                store[key] = dcp;
                index += amount;
                key++;
            }
            state = STATE_FINISH_RESTART;
            delay(1000);
            break;

        }
        case STATE_FINISH_RESTART: {

            state = STATE_INIT;
            break;

        }
    }

}
```

## dummyclass.h

*very minimal, constructor just stores a string in a character buffer. this object is just a wrapper.*

```
using namespace std;

class DummyClass {
    private:
        char* _container;

    public:
        DummyClass(){
        }

        DummyClass(string input){
            _container = new char[input.length()];
            strcpy(_container, input.c_str());
        }

        ~DummyClass(){
            delete _container;
            _container = nullptr;
        }

        char* ShowMeWhatYouGot(){
            return _container;
        }
};
```

## EDIT:

This is a real problem that I am having, I'm not sure why it is getting downvoted. Help me out here, how can I be more clear? I'm reluctant to shrink the code since it imitates many aspects of a much bigger program that it is modeling simply. I want to keep the structure of the code in place in case this bug is an emergent property.

Comment: This is too much code for this format. Please produce a [mcve]. Tools like valgrind can help you narrow down the problem, compile your code with debug information enabled to get more precise results.

Comment: This is a minimal example of a much bigger program with the same problem. I don't have access to valgrind bc this code is running on a microcontroller? Unless you know how I could run valgrind on the code...

Comment: This is neither minimal nor complete. And concerning valgrind: I just suggested a tool that is available and useful to many programmers, if you cannot use it, you need to find another way to reduce the problem.

Comment: Asking about valgrind was not sarcastic, though it seems it was taken that way. I actually don't  feel super well versed with this technology, and was reaching out for help.

Comment: It may be lengthy, but i'm not sure how I could make it more 'complete'. It is a 'complete' example of the bug I am facing. It actually has the bug. What could I do to 'complete' it?

Comment: Complete: Make us able to copy-paste, compile and run it. I did not take the valgrind part as you being sarcastic, I am aware that it is not available on every platform. It is however a tool I frequently use, I do not no all the tools for every platform out there. More specifically, I never worked on  a microcontroller, I have no idea how to debug there.

Comment: Not causing your leak, but in `~DummyClass()` replace `delete _container;` with `delete [] _container;`

Comment: @BaummitAugen I am absolutely sure that if you have a microcontroller that runs c++ and follows the same type of setup as arduino (main file has setup() and loop()), you can run this code. Only thing is that I edited the post to separate the main.cpp file out into sections so it would be easier to read. I also took out a lot of the comments in order to shrink the size of the code. Trying to make it as minimal as possible :/

Comment: @bgenchel - Look at this: `DummyClass* dcp = new DummyClass(buff_string.substr(index, amount));  store[key] = dcp;` --  What happens if an item already existed at `key` in the map?  You've got a memory leak.  Use `map::insert`, and you should really start to use smart pointers.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie my keys are integers from 0 to the number of objects; i'm just incrementing it, so they should be unique. And I empty the map before beginning to allocate more objects. maybe i'm missing something from what you are saying?

Comment: @bgenchel *so they should be unique.*  If I had a dollar for every time a programmer says "it should be* and it isn't, I would be a rich man.  Seriously, please *check* this by writing code, and not intuition.  You've got a leak, and the code I pointed out shouts out "leak!" to me.  Also, your `DummyClass` is seriously flawed if copies are made, let alone the wrong form of `delete` is used in the destructor (it should be `delete []`).  And why not just use `std::string` and leave the manual memory management alone?

Comment: how could I write code to test this. When I say *should*, I leave the uncertainty up to my irrational fear that things aren't happening the way I program them. If I am incrementing the number for every object, and the map is empty, those keys will be unique. I'll do a check though.

Comment: @bgenchel Use `map::insert`, not `operator [ ]`.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert.  And to check it, `insert` returns a `std::pair`.  The `second` of this pair tells if you if the new item was inserted.  If it comes back `false`, I get another dollar.  You could have also used `map::find` previous to this to see if the key exists.  Again, if `find` didn't return `end()`, I get a dollar.

Comment: I used count and did not see a problem? but, deal :)

Comment: unfortunately, neither of those things were the issue :/

Comment: In embedded systems, you should refrain from using the heap.  Fragmentation is just one of the issues, ownership and when to delete are others.  Try declaring the variable without using `new`.

Comment: unfortunately, in the actual system that this models, having allocated memory is necessary. So, since I want to solve the bug there, I need to allocate memory here.

Comment: not sure if this is causing a leak, but you're probably causing bad things to happen by allocating `_container = new char[input.length()];` and then `strcpy(_container, input.c_str());` (you didn't allocate space for the `\0`)

Comment: As a debugging strategy, add a global object id to each `DummyClass()`.   Every time you create a new object, increment the id and add it to a map or your collection of choice.  When you delete it, remove it from the collection.   After a while, check to ensure the collection is empty.   With this you can ensure you're deleting every object you're creating.

Comment: Another minor issue is the destructor blindly deletes `_container`.  If you had an object that is created with the default constructor, `_container` is undefined, so your behavior would be undefined.   I don't see that happening in the code as written above, but, something to worry about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always account for the string terminator:

```
    DummyClass(string input){
        _container = new char[input.length()];
        strcpy(_container, input.c_str());
    }
```

Allocates one too few bytes to hold the input string and terminator that is then copied into it.   The `\0`that's appended at the end is overwriting something, which is most likely metadata required to re-integrate the alloced memory fragment back into the heap successfully.   I'm actually surprised it didn't crash...

It probably doesn't happen every allocation (only when you overflow into a new 8 byte aligned chunk), but once is enough :)

Answer (score 0):

So, after some testing, I'd like to give a shout out to **Russ Schultz** who commented the right answer. If you want to post a solution formally, I would be happy to mark it as correct.

The memory bug is caused by allocating the char buffer _container without considering the null terminating character, meaning I am loading in a string that is too big. (not entirely sure why this causes a bug and doesn't throw an error?)

On a different site however, I also received this piece of advice:

> ```
>             string chunk;
>             for(char i = 0; i < 200; i++){
>                 int index = rand() % alphabet_range;
>                 chunk.append(alphabet.substr(index, 1));
>                 // strcat(buffer, alphabet.substring(index, index + 1));
>                 num_chars++;
>             }
> ```
>
> This loop looks suspect to me. You are depending on the string append method to grow chunk as needed, but you know you are going to run that loop 200 times. Why not use the string reserve method to just allocate that much space? I bet that this chews up a lot of memory with each new char you append calling realloc, potentially fragmenting memory.

This ended up not being the solution, but it might be good to know.

Comment: When you overrun a buffer in the free store, it can corrupt the information about memory that is allocated, or other allocated memory.  The result can be crashes, leaks, or data corruptions.  Depending on what the overwritten data was.

Comment: Why do people keep downvoting me. I'm seriously confused. I thought the point of this site was to ask questions and spread knowledge. All I've done here is ask a question about an issue that I was having, and try to be nice and give credit for the answer. My reputation is already pretty low; I feel like I am being treated extremely unfairly, and I'm definitely not being encouraged to reach out for any more help.

Comment: I've upvoted the question as you clearly put a lot of effort into it, though I don't recommend you add too much meta-commentary to questions or answers (it is not of interest to most readers and is often edited out). For your answer, I would tend to recommend that if you are adding an addendum but that someone else broadly solved it, you could set it as Community Wiki, which means that any votes upon it do not affect your score.

Comment: (I think the C++ tag does tend to be more stringent about MCVEs - it's perhaps the exacting nature of people who are inclined more towards low-level languages. If you get a couple of downvotes then don't worry about it - commenting that one is unhappy unfortunately can attract more of the same!)